# how to extract a list of lists (containing any value type) from json

Tags: python, json, list, postgresql

From a mobile client, we're sending a list of lists as part of a json to the server(python 2.7). This needs to be split into individual lists for processing. 
Example json = {"table":"[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],....]"}

What I need is to extract individual lists [1,2,3],[2,4,5] etc, add an extra object at the start of the list and insert them into a postgres DB.

For extracting the json I use :

post_data = json.loads(request.data) 
table = post_data['table']

print table prints u'[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]'.

I checked a couple of questions and use the following snippet for processing and inserting into db.

```
tbl = post_data['table']
table = ast.literal_eval(tbl)
print table

tup_table = []
for lst in table :
    lst.insert(0,userid)
    tup_table += [tuple(lst)]

connection = engine.raw_connection()
cur = connection.cursor()
records_list_template = ','.join(['%s'] * len(tup_table))
insert_query = 'insert into stats(userid,rid,val,fid) values {0}'.format(records_list_template)
cur.execute(insert_query, tup_table)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

The problem however is ast.literal_eval() works fine in this example but does not work when the list in json contains values of other types. For e.g when the list is [[1,abc,3],[2,bcd,4]] it returns an error ValueError('malformed string')

I've tried using table.encode('utf-8') instead. That returns a list type but the for loop loop does not extract a sub-list and it extracts each character in the list separately.

Is there a better way of extracting a list from the unicode and fetching the sublist for creating the tuple ?

Answer (score 1):

Like your error message indicates, the given json file is malformed. You forgot the quotes.

Change `[[1,abc,3],[2,bcd,4]]` to `[[1,"abc",3],[2,"bcd",4]]`.

Comment: stupid followup question. I had actually tried doing this. Since I use a postman client to test it, it was not allowing me to add double-quoted string within a double-quote. How do I do that in postman?

Comment: You have to escape the quotes by inserting a backslash before a quote in a string (`\"`)

Comment: i was trying \\\" which was suggested in another forum which never worked : It works!! Is ast.literal_val the best way of doing this, would it work for all types of strings/text (including single-quote, double-quote, \n etc) ?